# why drand48 () show same value in each run in my program?

Tags: swift, random, swift2

I try to create a variable to get value random with  ***drand48 ()*** but in each run my variable take a same value . 
can anybody help me , (i want in each run my variable take different value) ???

```
let number = drand48 ()
```

Comment: Have read the documentation for `drand48`? You need to seed it.

Comment: can you tell me about it ??

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but in many cases, `arc4random()` or `arc4random_uniform()` is a better choice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

drand48 creates a Pseudo-random number sequence. That is if it is not set to a different start point each time it will always produce the same numbers.

To fix this call srand48 beforehand to set a new start point for drand48

Eg

```
let time = UInt32(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
srand48(Int(time))
let number = drand48 ()
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/drand48.3.html) are the docs for drand48 and srand48

Edit: different way to seed to avoid the error, I'm not by a computer (on my phone) so may have to fix it later if it doesn't work

Comment: what do **srand48** exactly ??

Comment: The `srand48` function seeds the pseudorandom number generator.

Comment: also i can run my code ** Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<time_t>' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>')**

Comment: Exactly, I'll add the documentation for drand48 and its family functions to my answer

Comment: thanks , it works but a little note : you must change **srand48(time)** to **srand48(Int(time))**

Comment: A nice, I'll change my answer now. Cheers for the heads up!

Comment: Or `srand48(Int(time(nil)))`.

Comment: Pseudo-random, not sudo-random.